# IIS concurrent handling of request slow

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, concurrency

In IIS, I have set the "Maximum worker processes" to 16 in application pool setting. Now, I have a request which will load for some time. At the same time, if another request is submitted, this request will not respond until the previous request finished loading. I am curious that I already set the worker process to 16. Is that supposed that IIS will handle the request concurrently with the available worker process? But as I observed, the latter request have response only after the previous request finished. Is that the requests are queued in only one worker process so that make it waiting? How can I make IIS handle the request concurrently without the waiting?

Comment: Please set "maximum worker processes" to 1. Increasing it won't give you concurrent handling, but usually hide the true culprit. Your description shows typical coding mistakes like using locks in the wrong way, so only debugging it carefully can show the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Lex. May I know more the possible issues in my code that block the request? I can narrow down it to find out the bug.

Comment: Nope. Too many ways you can lock up resources mistakenly, so it is too broad to discuss such. Please learn tools such as profilers, or find a more senior guy in your team to help. If no such can be found, you can also open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com .